# Efficiency formula for passive complex circuit

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, passive-networks, efficiency

I want to find a formula for the efficiency of this circuit, so \$\eta=P_{out}/P_{in}\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHqIdP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that the real power is given by \$P=VI\cos \phi\$, I also know that the current is given by \$I=V/Z\$ with \$Z\$ being the impedance of the circuit. But how do I find \$\phi\$?

Comment: Is the L and C chosen to produce an impedance match at a particular frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's first derive a general formula for the efficiency:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\eta&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{o}}{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{i}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\text{I}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{o}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\text{I}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}}{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right|}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi_\text{o}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}}{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}\cdot\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right|}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}}{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}}\right)^2\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi_\text{o}\right)}{\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)}\\
\\
&=\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|^2\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right|}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi_\text{o}\right)}{\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)}\\
\\
&=\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|^2\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right|}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\cos\left(\arg\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right)\right)}{\displaystyle\cos\left(\arg\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\right)}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Where \$\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{o}\$ is the output power, \$\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{i}\$ is the input power, \$\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\$ is the output RMS-voltage, \$\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\$ is the input RMS-voltage, \$\displaystyle\text{I}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\$ is the output RMS-current, \$\displaystyle\text{I}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{RMS}}\$ is the input RMS-current, \$\displaystyle\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\$ is the output impedance, \$\displaystyle\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\$ is the input impedance, \$\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi_\text{o}\right)\$ is the power factor of the output, \$\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)\$ is the power factor of the input and \$\displaystyle\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\$ is the transfer function of the circuit which is defined by the output voltage divided by the input voltage.

So, now we can find all the individual pieces and we start with the easy ones:

- $$\displaystyle\arg\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right)=\arg\left(\text{R}_\text{load}\right)=0\tag2$$
- $$\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{o}}\right|=\left|\text{R}_\text{load}\right|=\text{R}_\text{load}\tag3$$

Now, to the more complicated ones:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\displaystyle\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}_\text{load}\right)\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_\text{load}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}}\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}\left(1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}+\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}_\text{load}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\right)\text{j}
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, we get:

$$\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|=\sqrt{\left(\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\right)^2+\left(\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}_\text{load}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\right)\right)^2}\tag5$$

Let's find:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\displaystyle\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)&=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}_\text{load}\right)}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_\text{load}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_\text{load}}}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}}}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\left(1+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)+\text{R}_\text{load}}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\text{R}-\text{CLR}_\text{load}\omega^2+\left(\omega\text{L}+\omega\text{CRR}_\text{load}\right)\text{j}+\text{R}_\text{load}}\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{load}\left(1-\text{CL}\omega^2\right)+\omega\left(\text{L}+\text{CRR}_\text{load}\right)\text{j}}
\end{split}\tag6
\end{equation}

So, we get:

$$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|^2=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}^2}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{load}\left(1-\text{CL}\omega^2\right)\right)^2+\left(\omega\left(\text{L}+\text{CRR}_\text{load}\right)\right)^2}\tag7$$

Now, the last piece of the puzzle (we can use the result obtained in \$(4)\$):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\displaystyle\arg\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)&=\displaystyle\arg\left(\underbrace{\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}}_{:=\space\Re\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}+\underbrace{\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}_\text{load}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_\text{load}\right)^2}\right)}_{:=\space\Im\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}\cdot\text{j}\right)\\
\\
&=\displaystyle\begin{cases}
\displaystyle0&\space\text{if}\space\displaystyle\Re\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Im\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=0\\
\\
\displaystyle\arctan\left(\frac{\Im\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}{\Re\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\displaystyle\Re\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Im\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\\
\\
\displaystyle\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\Re\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)}{\left|\Im\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\right|}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\displaystyle\Re\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)>0\space\wedge\space\Im\left(\space\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)<0
\end{cases}
\end{split}\tag8
\end{equation}

I used Mathematica to simplify everything and found:

$$\eta=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{load}\left(1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2\right)}\tag9$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I can see that you put a lot of effort into this. I'll go over the details.